# Dynamically added object properties not being added in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, closures, scope-chain

Please <strike>bare</strike> bear with me, I'm very new to Javascript. I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out why this won't work. Keep in mind I come from a Java background. I have a function 'getCsvData' and I'm essentially trying to parse a CSV file and dynamically add object properties to the datasource object and then return it. As you can see, outside the function 'getCsvData', I try to log the results after calling my function, but the result object is empty and there are no object propeties added to it.

I have a very strong feeling it has to due with closure/scope chain resolution that I'm still trying to learn and understand.

The questions are: Why aren't the properties added dynamically to the datasource object? I believe they actually are added in the scope of the anonymous function 'function(data)' passed as the second argument to '$.get', but they are immediately gone once the outer function 'getCsvData' returns. Why, and how can I fix this? Thanks!!

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/globalize.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dx.chartjs.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.parse.js"></script>

$(function () {
    function getCsvData(fileName, groupBy, year) {
        var datasource = { }
        $.get(fileName, function(data) {
            var alldata = $.parse(data, { header: true });
            for (var i = 0; i<alldata.results.rows.length;i++) {
                var key = alldata.results.rows[i][groupBy]
                if (key in datasource) {
                    datasource[key] = datasource[key] + 1
                } else {
                    datasource[key] = 0
                }
             }
         });
        return datasource;
    };


    var results = getCsvData("data/data.csv", "Priority", 2012);
    console.log(results)
    for (key in results) {
        console.log(key)
    }
});
```

Comment: Yet another "why doesn't my asynchronous function update immediately?" question. ;-)

Comment: @RobG, actually I totally forgot that $.get would be async by default, if I had realized that earlier, it would have made this so much easier! Thanks!

Comment: That's OK, you're one of millions who've said "doh!!" to that. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `get` is called async, so `datasource` is the return value after initiating the `get` rather than after receiving the result (i.e. it is empty because the `get` completion has not been called yet). You should rather indicate completion with a callback or use `jQuery.ajax()` with the `sync` option to wait for the response to the `get` before returning from `getCsvData`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133327/746754).